# Openai Spaces for a modified environment

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

I have a 2-dimensional array of normalized data. I am using

```
space = np.array([0,1,...366],[0,0.000001,.....1])
```

I need to fit this as an observation space in reinforcement learning. I have extended the open ai gym and created a custom made environment. How to fit in this 2-dimensional array in openAI spaces. 
Can I use Box, DiscreteSpace or MultiDiscrete space? Can anyone help me with a sample code to fit this in observation space?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems you simply can return a 2D vector and extract out the components for that. You can take a look at the MountainCar example under classic control envs for a fully working case. But something like:

```
vec_1_low = 0
vec_1_high = 366
vec_2_low = 0
vec_2_high = 1

space_low = np.array([vec_1_low, vec_2_low])

space_high = np.array([vec_1_high, vec_2_high])

obs = spaces.Box(space_low, space_high, dtype=np.float32)
```

Then:

```
vec1_obs, vec2_obs = obs.sample()
```